# Compilation error while trying to implement an iterator that borrows some data and owns other data

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement an iterator :

```
struct MyIterator<'a> {
    s1: &'a str,
    s2: String,

    idx: usize,
}

impl<'a> MyIterator<'a> {
    fn new(s1: &str) -> MyIterator {
        MyIterator {
            s1: s1,
            s2: "Rust".to_string(),

            idx: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.idx += 1;

        match self.idx {
            1 => Some(self.s1),
            2 => Some(&self.s2),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this very detailed error message but I can't figure how to fix the code:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\main.rs:39:23
   |
39 |             2 => Some(&self.s2),
   |                       ^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 34:5...
  --> src\main.rs:34:5
   |
34 | /     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
35 | |         self.idx + 1;
36 | |
37 | |         match self.idx {
...  |
41 | |         }
42 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src\main.rs:39:23
   |
39 |             2 => Some(&self.s2),
   |                       ^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 31:1...
  --> src\main.rs:31:1
   |
31 | / impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
32 | |     type Item = &'a str;
33 | |
34 | |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
...  |
42 | |     }
43 | | }
   | |_^
note: ...so that types are compatible (expected std::iter::Iterator, found std::iter::Iterator)
  --> src\main.rs:34:46
   |
34 |       fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |  ______________________________________________^
35 | |         self.idx + 1;
36 | |
37 | |         match self.idx {
...  |
41 | |         }
42 | |     }
```

Why isn't `s2` lifetime simply `'a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned value has type `Option<&'a str>`, but `'a` doesn't keep the `MyIterator<'a>` alive, so it could go out of scope, and with it the contained `s2: String`.  So `'a` simply doesn't keep `s2` alive.  (It only keeps `s1` alive, which would be easier to see if you'd have written `fn new(s1: &'a str) -> MyIterator<'a>`)

Furthermore the [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait is designed in a way you can **never** return a reference to something stored in the `Iterator` itself in the `next` function.

Instead you could create a type storing the value and implement [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) for a reference to it (with a separate iterator type containing a reference to the storage object).

Comment: Do you mean I need to write 3 structs? `Data`, `DataIntoIterator` and `DataIterator`? I'm not sure that the `IntoIterator` implementation could return a reference here since the trait accepts an owned version of `Data`

Comment: No, just `Data` and `DataIterator<'a>`; then `impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a Data { type IntoIter = DataIterator<'a>; ... }`. Use it like `let d = Data::new(...); for i in &d { ... }`